Converting between latitude/longitude and non-standard x/y projections
I am using R and I have two datasets of the following:
df=data.frame(longitude = c(-113.2692,
                            -113.1958,
                            -113.2072),
              latitude = c(33.85247,
                           35.93505,
                           34.78221),
              x = c(498.1510,
                    491.4281,
                    497.8512),
              y = c(-402.4295,
                    -172.3635,
                    -300.0663))

df2 = data.frame(x = c(-384.0567,
                       -345.0019,
                       -145.5592),
                 y = c(527.5961,
                       537.3394,
                       495.8191))

The variables in latitude and longitude in df are in decimal degree format (WGS 84). The variables in x and y in the df and df2 datasets are points on a non-standard projection.
Assuming the x and y variables in df are projected from the decimal degrees in the latitude and longitude variables, is it possible find or define this projection, to then use it to map the coordinates of x and y in df2?

Anything is possible. What have you tried and where are you stuck.

I've tried finding a standard projection via projfinder but nothing was correct. I'm unsure where to begin beyond that or if there is a tool available.

Comparing st_distance() on your lat-long with dist() on your x-y indicates that x-y are in kilometres, but trying x1000 and y1000 in projfinder doesn't find anything there either (between Kingman and Phoenix, yes?) Are you sure the signs are right, because negative Y values mean an origin N of your df locations. Also, latitude is linear with y (in your 3 points) but longitude is very non-linear with y which would make extrapolating to those big negative x values in df2 tricky.

I'm a bit concerned by your use of "similar to" here - are these three actual points from the data? Because comparing a scatter plot of long-lat and a plot of X-Y shows very different plots, which over a small area shouldn't be the case.

I'm hopelessly confused. Which set of X and Y do you want to use to represent your lats and longs?

@Pointdump I think (and OP needs to clarify) the fundamental question is: df represents the lat-long and x-y of the same three point locations. Using those for georeferencing, what is the lat-long of the x-y values in df2?

@Spacedman, OK I think I understand now.

@Pointdump I edited for clarity, I think this should make more sense now.

@Spacedman Yes, that is the question.

@geoscience123, what are your units? Feet(International or US Survey) or Meters? Probably a custom Affine Projection will get what you need.

@Pointdump as I discovered, using distances, it looks like the x and y coords are in kilometres, because then you get the similar distances between the x-y coords as the lat-long coords. However, if you scatter plot, there's no simple linear transform between them, which I'd expect over a small (few degrees max) area for any sensible projection. With only 3 calibration locations, and the 3 question points being so far from them, I think this is impossible to do with any useful precision.

@Spacedman, The actual dataset I have is 90 points in total.

I guess the big question is where did you get this data, and is there any metadata information with it?

If you plot the 90 points X-Y coordinates, and also plot the 90 points lat-long coordinates, does it look like there's a simple transformation between them? Can you edit your Q and show these plots? For the three points you gave, I don't have much hope because it has to be a very non-linear and possibly complex transformation. But with 90 points there might be enough information to do it.

In principle yes, in practice maybe not.
This is essentially the same process as that of georeferencing an image. You identify known points on the image by their pixel locations with known points on the ground. So for example a junction on a street map is at pixel location (124, 733) pixels, and you know it is at lat-long 57.24N 2.1E. Once you have a few of those then software can work out how to transform the full image to its lat-long location.
The complication is in the unknown functional form of the transform. If the image is a good scan of a cartographic map then it may only need a few points to get the correct linear transformation, with a shift, scale and possibly rotation of the image. If the image comes from a hand-drawn map or from distorted paper or a bad scan then with more reference points the image can be warped like a rubber sheet to match up the known good points.
With the three points in your question, there seems to be no simple linear mapping between XY and lat-long. Without seeing more points, or without accepting possible massive uncertainties in predicted locations of unknown points, this cannot be done.
If instead, for example, plotting XY and lat-long for your points resulted in a perfect equilateral triangle in both cases, then a simple scale from XY to lat-long would work and might be applicable to all XY coordinates. This might even be a defined well-known projection in the EPSG catalogue. But that too is impossible to tell from these three points, and looks unlikely given the shape of the plots generated by them.

Yes this makes sense. I suppose I should've used the word georeference in my question. I guess I was wondering if there was a simple package to do such a thing, but it appears not. I was provided this data by a professor and I do not have access to the metadata.
